# Deploying code in test

Tags: scala

I have [a library](https://github.com/Lasering/scala-expect) in which I created [a very useful class](https://github.com/Lasering/scala-expect/blob/master/src/test/scala/work/martins/simon/expect/TestUtils.scala) in src/**test**/scala. How do I go about making this class available to users so that they can use this class in their tests?

If I migrate this test class to src/main/scala and deploy it then my library will need to have the testing framework as a dependency.

If I deploy the artifacts in test then the tests of my library will also be packaged which is stupid since people using my library dont need to have access to the library tests.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what it is you find particularly "useful" about that class, and, especially, about the scalatest `Futures` it uses ... Being able to call `f.futureValue` rather than `Await.result(f)` can't be it, can it?

Comment: `Await.result` is synchronous where as ScalaTest `futureValue` is asynchronous. The usefulness resides in the fact that I don't need to redefine the `PatienceConfig`.

Comment: Asynchronous? What do you mean by that? In my book, to be "asynchronous"  something needs to return a `Future` ... but you already have a `Future`. Clearly, you must have some kind of a different meaning in mind for that term?

Comment: If you want to factor it out to use in tests for multiple projects, publish it as it's own artifact, and declare the dependency in the `test` scope in sbt, so that the build won't actually depend on it.

Comment: @Dima you are correct. I confused the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of the dependency on scalatest, you don't need that stuff:

```
  trait VeryUsefulTrait { 

    implicit class RichExpect[T](expect: Expect[T]) {
      val timeout = expect.settings.timeout + 1.second
      def failedFutureValue: Throwable = Await.result(expect.run().failed, timeout)
      def futureValue: T = Await.result(expect.run(), timeout)
      def whenReady[U](f: T => U): U = f(Await.result(expect.run(), timeout))
  }
```